# "Visual Studio 16 2019" stopped working with GitHub Actions

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, github-actions

I have a project using GitHub Actions and I'm still on Visual Studio 16 2019. However my build job just stopped working after months of working just fine.

My job is running on `windows-latest` like so:

```
jobs:
  build-windows:
    runs-on: windows-latest
```

And then I'm generating the build files with CMake like so:

```
    - name: Configure CMake
      shell: bash
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/build
      run: cmake $GITHUB_WORKSPACE -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DBUILD_UNIT_TESTS=ON
```

However, without doing any changes the Windows builds have started failing:

```
Run cmake $GITHUB_WORKSPACE -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DBUILD_UNIT_TESTS=ON
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Generator
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "D:/a/ttvg/ttvg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Visual Studio 16 2019

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

A link to the full GitHub Action file is here: https://github.com/zethon/ttvg/blob/master/.github/workflows/windows.yml

A link to the last build job can be found here: https://github.com/zethon/ttvg/runs/5352280995?check_suite_focus=true

Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The `windows-latest` images are being migrated from Server 2019 & VS 2019 to Server2011 & VS 2022. If your build script _must_ use 2019 then that might be the cause. See https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-11-github-actions-jobs-running-on-windows-latest-are-now-running-on-windows-server-2022/

Comment: That should be Server 2022 & VS 2022 of course.

Answer (score 4):

Specifying the `windows-2019` instance instead of `windows-latest` should fix this, until the 2019 image gets deprecated.

```
jobs:
  build-windows:
    runs-on: windows-2019
```